Why the plural lighting lamps in the courtyards in Al Ha-Nissim of Hanukkah
Near the end of Al Ha-Nissim of Hanukkah we read of lighting lamps in the courtyards. If the lights refer to the menorah, why the plural "courtyards"? The menorah was in just one courtyard.

"The menorah was in just one courtyard." Source? In Hallel this morning you said בְּחַצְר֤וֹת ׀ בֵּ֤ית יְהוָ֗ה בְּֽת֮וֹכֵ֤כִי יְֽרוּשָׁלִָ֗ם הַֽלְלוּ־יָֽהּ:

@DoubleAA What you quote (apparently from Psalm 116:19) does not refer to the menorah. It means the Temple consisted of or contained courtyards. Do you read it differently?

@DoubleAA The menorah was in the heichal on the southern wall: Exodus.26.34

There were multiple lamps in multiple courtyards.
Solomon added 10 menorahs, but all in the Heichal:
ואם תאמר חמשה מימין הפתח וחמשה משמאל הפתח אם כן מצינו מנורה בצפון והתורה אמרה (שמות כו, לה) ואת המנורה נכח השולחן 
And if you say that the terms “right” and “left” are referring to the two sides of the entrance to the Sanctuary, this is difficult. According to this interpretation, Solomon placed five candelabra to the right of the entrance, on the north side, and five candelabra to the left of the entrance, on the south side. If so, we find that in the case of the five candelabra to the right of the entrance, the candelabrum was placed in the north of the Sanctuary. But the Torah said: “And you shall set the Table outside the Curtain, and the Candelabrum opposite the Table on the side of the Tabernacle toward the south, and you shall put the Table on the north side” (Exodus 26:35).
Source: https://www.sefaria.org/Menachot.98b.7-8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en
Menachot 98b
Also, There were golden candelabra atop poles there in the (Women's) Courtyard.
בְּמוֹצָאֵי יוֹם טוֹב הָרִאשׁוֹן שֶׁל חָג, יָרְדוּ לְעֶזְרַת נָשִׁים, וּמְתַקְּנִין שָׁם תִּקּוּן גָּדוֹל. וּמְנוֹרוֹת שֶׁל זָהָב הָיוּ שָׁם, וְאַרְבָּעָה סְפָלִים שֶׁל זָהָב בְּרָאשֵׁיהֶן, וְאַרְבָּעָה סֻלָּמוֹת לְכָל אֶחָד וְאֶחָד, וְאַרְבָּעָה יְלָדִים מִפִּרְחֵי כְהֻנָּה וּבִידֵיהֶם כַּדִּים שֶׁל שֶׁמֶן שֶׁל מֵאָה וְעֶשְׂרִים לֹג, שֶׁהֵן מַטִּילִין לְכָל סֵפֶל וָסֵפֶל:   
This was the sequence of events: At the conclusion of the first Festival day the priests and the Levites descended from the Israelites’ courtyard to the Women’s Courtyard, where they would introduce a significant repair, as the Gemara will explain. There were golden candelabra atop poles there in the courtyard. And there were four basins made of gold at the top of each candelabrum. And there were four ladders for each and every pole and there were four children from the priesthood trainees, and in their hands were pitchers with a capacity of 120 log of oil that they would pour into each and every basin.
Source: https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Sukkah.5.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en 
Mishna Sukka 5:2
